# multiple Drag n Drop html jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I would like to create a drag n drop system on a list of element.
Here a picture of what I am expecting :
[image]

I would to take red square 1, put it in first square black. and if I take red square 2 and I put it in black square 1, it removes the red square 1 (which go back in the list of red squares) and put red square 2 instead.

Here what I am trying, but it doesn't do the job !

html :

```
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                  <li><div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> ceci est un test 1</div></li>
                                  <li><div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> ceci est un test 2</div></li>
                                  <li><div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> ceci est un test 3</div></li>
                                </ul>
```

jquery :

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: One option is to invoke the power of the [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) plugin, possibly along with draggable. It's made my life at work a lot easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Change id's as application cannot understand to which block you are trying to drag**

```
 <ul class="list-inline">
                                  <li><div id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> ceci est un test 1</div></li>
                                  <li><div id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> ceci est un test 2</div></li>
                                  <li><div id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> ceci est un test 3</div></li>
                                </ul>
```

Comment: Ok, it solves a part of my problem. but if I drag two in one box, they still stay both in. How can I remove the one is in when I drag a second one ?

Comment: on drag set the second container to initial level and drop the only single instance which ever you are droping

Comment: can you place the full code i mean jsfiddle so that i can help you out

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Here the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9ohqpq6L/ . The problem : on my localhost, the drag works, but on fiddle not :-/

Comment: Thanks for your help :) keep me in touch !